# Can I set a value to a radio button in Java?

Tags: java, radio-button

It's possible set a value to a radio in Java? If the radio is selected, I get the value of them.

EDIT: the value is some like: radio1 = value 10, radio2, value = 15, radio3 = value 30, etc, not if it is selected or not.

Comment: Yes, but the specifics will depend on which Java Radio Button class you are using.

Comment: [Radio](http://teesdiary.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/old-school-radio-image.jpg)? Also, have you bothered to look at [The Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton)?

Comment: I believe I have answered your question - take a look. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a value:

```
JRadioButton rb = new JRadioButton(Integer.toString(10));
```

To get value of selected:

```
rb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("Selected value = " +  e.getActionCommand());
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

If you have multiple radio buttons that perform the same action when selected, I'd suggest all of them register the same `ActionListener`:

```
private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      System.out.println("Selected value = " +  e.getActionCommand());
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

To select from code, you can use

```
 JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("Select Me");
 rb1.setSelected(true);
```

and to get selection

```
 boolean selected = rb1.isSelected();
```